# HTTP response time

Tags: networking, http, curl, python3

I want to ask a stupid question.
Just using curl as an example. 
If we use `curl -I https://a_big_file.com`, maybe the big file upto 600MB, but i surprised to found it only used 0.160s, which is unbelieveable. (I got this time using curl @fortmat like %{time_total}).

And i use python3, `urllib.request.urlopen('https://a_big_file.com')`, also using about 0.160s. that`s amazing.

so my question is, does the response time represent the whole http communication was finished? or just the first byte return and the client can read.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, may be there are some mistake for me, all above are `ftp://`, very sorry for that. but i still don`t know why.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in network app performance terminology, "response time" is usually either time to the first byte of the response headers, or maybe time to the first byte of the response payload. It's usually not the complete time for the whole transfer.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, and I want to ask one more question base on above. If the response is very small such as 400B, does the HTTP connection still connect and wait the client read ? I amuse it will auto send the whole respone and then close the connection. thanks in advance.